# Does #include increase the RAM usage?

Tags: c, memory, heap-memory, ram, stack-memory

If I include more header files, will it increase the RAM size required? For example, will I need more RAM if I `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <string.h>` ?

I am writing an embedded system software with CNU C compiler, so I want to minimize the RAM needed as much as possible.

Comment: Increase the RAM size required for the program you're compiling or increase the RAM size required by the compiler itself?

Comment: I mean the RAM size required for the program I am compiling, I only have 64KB internal RAM in the micro-controller, and I always worry that it runs out of RAM because it it very hard to debug...

Comment: Wow in the first place I think my question seems stupid and too trivial, I had wondered should I asked it....but now I think it is worth asking as so many different answers and comments...

Answer (score 1):

The answer to what you really want to ask is probably "no", at least when you're talking about the standard library headers. Including them will not make a difference to executable size or memory footprint. Nevertheless, I can't resist giving a contrary response:

It depends on what's in your included file. The system headers won't do it, but in theory, anything can be in that file. That a header just contains function prototypes and type definitions is just a convention. If I have these two files:

```
// foo.c
int bigarray[1000];
```

and

```
// bar.c
#include "foo.c"
int main(int argc, char**argv()) {
return 0;
}
```

that's legal code and bar.c will compile nicely, but my memory footprint might well be 4K larger because of the array in foo.c (if the compiler doesn't optimize it out).

Comment: This code isn't including a header file. Anyone attempting to include .c files only have themselves to blame. Apart from that, it is very unlikely that the compiler will include "bigarray" in the executable.

Comment: "Header files" are a convention in C. The compiler doesn't care what you name the file or what you write in it. Also, I did say I was trying to be contrary :-) As for not including bigarray in the executable, try this: gcc -o bar bar.c && nm bar | grep bigarray

Comment: It doesn't matter what the compiler accepts, because the OP specifically asked what would happen if they included header files and your code is not doing that, so it doesn't answer the question. Running the compiler without any optimizations enabled isn't relevant either.

Comment: Rename "foo.c" to "foo.h", and change "#include \"foo.c\"" to "#include \"foo.h\"" then. :P

Answer (score 0):

No, include files are for the compiler; they do not affect the size of the generated code at all.

Answer (score 0):

No. Include files are not functions, they are references to system functions (at least for the ones that come with your compiler). If you want to see for yourself, navigate to the `include` directory of your compiler and open the files in a text editor (BUT NEVER CHANGE THEM). They are the same as any other `.h` that you write; they do not define any functions.

The compiler will see that the function name (ex. printf) is valid an compile it to an object file. The linker takes care of turning that name into a valid system call.

Comment: I see you using the word kernel. I do not think it means what you think it means.

Comment: Was wondering the same :) I think he meant "core" instead. Or may be I'm wrong. System functions would be wrong, as some include point to higher level functions.

Comment: @Enno its just in my operating system that i wrote and the linker script i wrote, they are kernel calls

Answer (score 0):

Headers inclusion is only effective during compilation time. They are used to tell the compiler where he can find the implementations he needs.

The compiled executable doesn't hold these informations, thus is not affected by the number of includes.

This is a huge difference with interpreted language like PHP where including file can increase the memory usage. But even in PHP there are mechanism that minimizes memory usage (including a file once, excluding unused include...)

Answer (score 0):

yes, I may increase the binary size, and then increase the RAM size.
It comes two ways:
1. The head file has global/static variables definition
2. The head file has the function even it isn't used for current file. But the compiler may still keep them in final binary.

I say "may increase" because if the compiler is smart enough, I can only includes the data necessary the binary, but discard others。

for other content maybe in head file, like variables declaration， typedef etc. they will not increase the RAM because it only be required in compiling time, not run time.

Comment: The compiler will most likely only keep them in the final binary if those globals/statics are actually used by the program. Also, standard library header files are usually written by skilled, professional programmers, so you won't find any globals/statics in the headers.

Comment: @Lundin I am saying the probability. I am not the writer of library, so I don't how they write. You are not, so you don't know ether.

Comment: Err... actually I do. Most compilers keep their headers fully open source.

Answer (score -1):

Yes but only slightly.. but it does increase the CPU usage. you can check it in the Windows Task Manager....

Comment: I think it is quite obvious that the OP means the RAM consumption of the executable, not of the compiler. Also, there is nothing in the question indicating that the code is compiled on MS Windows.